# grep log file for only X newest entries of special value

Tags: linux, file, shell, grep, ksh

I want to get (only!) the three newest entries with type "ERROR:" from a log file.
(Or the last 5 warnings, etc...)
The latest three entries from botton to top, the log file is written permanently.

How can i get the outout of a log file like this?

example log file:

INFO: message text line 1.....
      message text line 2.....

ERROR: message text line 1.....
       message text line 2.....

WARNING: message text line 1.....
         message text line 2.....

ERROR: message text line 1.....
       message text line 2.....

INFO: message text line 1.....
      message text line 2.....

INFO: message text line 1.....
      message text line 2.....

WARNING: message text line 1.....
         message text line 2.....

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you LAST 3  ERROR OR WARNING. hope this helps

egrep "ERROR|WARNING" YOURFILE | tail -n 3

Tharanga Abeyseela

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine `grep` with `tail`. Something like this:

```
grep ERROR logfile.log | tail -n 3
```